# Get Data from PostgreSQL to Django and display it in html

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL database that contains two columns ID and Name. I am using django framework to get the data from the database and I want to display the data into html page. The problem is that the retrieved data is without columns name. It looks like this, and in order to use it in the html page it has to have a key for each tuple.

```
[(2, 'abc'), (3, 'subhi')]
```

I've tried to get the columns name but they are only table columns without data. Below is my Code:

models.py

```
import psycopg2
import pprint

def main():
    conn_string = "host='localhost' dbname='music' user='postgres' password='subhi123'"

    column_names = []
    data_rows = []

    with psycopg2.connect(conn_string) as connection:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("select id, name from music")
            column_names = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
            for row in cursor:
                data_rows.append(row)
                records = cursor.fetchall()

                # print out the records using pretty print
                # note that the NAMES of the columns are not shown, instead just indexes.
                # for most people this isn't very useful so we'll show you how to return
                # columns as a dictionary (hash) in the next example.
                pprint.pprint(records)
                print (type(records))

    print("Column names: {}\n".format(column_names))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

views.py

```
from django.http import Http404

from django.shortcuts import render
from  .models import main


def index (request):
    all_albums = main()
    return  render(request,'music/index.html',{ 'all_albums' :all_albums})
```

index.html

```
{%  if all_albums  %}

<ul>
    {%  for album in all_albums  %}
    <li> <a href="/music/{{ album}}/">{{ album }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% else %}
<h3> You don't have any data</h3>

{%  endif %}
```

and the settings.py for which shows the PostgreSQL  connection:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'music',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'subhi123',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not using Django to retrieve data from DB. Look at you file `models.py`, you d'ont import anything from Django but only `psycopg2` which is the well known PostgreSQL connector for Python. You copy/pasted this code from https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Using_psycopg2_with_PostgreSQL, so follow the advise in comment, and read the next part, titled `Select/Fetch Records with Column Names`

Comment: @Antwane how to use the django to retrieve data from DB? I'm beginner to django

Answer (score 6, accepted):

django use ORM(Object-related maping) for db. It's called `Model` in django.

It means, you should make `Model` class for your db table and scheme, and django automatically make `sql` for the model - so you don't do sql job untill you need to.

Below is example of models. (example in docs)

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Django create database table like...

```
CREATE TABLE myapp_person (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "first_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "last_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL
);
```

It's hard to explain all in the answer, so you must look django official docs. After following tutorials (it's well written!), you can understand django - so at least, follow tutorials.

Here's some sites for help.

- [django tutorials](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/) - Highly recommend
- [django Models docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/)
- [django girls tutorial](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/) - pretty good tutorials, support many languages.
- [Introducing django ORM](https://opensource.com/article/17/11/django-orm)

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to use Django module i.e models.py (inherites by django.db.models.Model) this module creates data fields based on your choice and migrate them to the database (in your case Postgresql) when you hit enter by typing in "python manage.py migrate" without string. Possibly due to the fact of this you ain't attaining anything from Database.